# converting segd data to SU format using seismic unix

Tags: seismic

I tried to convert segd format to su format using seismic unix by below command:

```
segdread tape=1.segd > 1.su
```

but I have an error:

```
segdread: Error with length of first record
    ... first record = 270320 bytes differs from ((1 + n_gh + n_str * (n_cs + n_sk) + n_ec + n_ex) * 32)
        with n_gh=2, n_str=1, n_cs=16, n_sk=0, n_ec=32, n_ex=32
```

I would be grateful if you could help me to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

SEG-D is an uncommon format. From my experience, here is how you need to approach this problem. You can't easily jump straight from SEG-D to SU. I've had extensive experience with SU and the best methodology is to first take your current seismic data type (SEG-D) and convert to SEG-Y. Only after converting to SEG-Y format can you then jump to SU.

So, here is an outline and workflow of a solution:

> 1.) Download and use this tool for SEG-D to SEG-Y format: http://users.chariot.net.au/~witek/segd2segy.htm
>
> 2.) Now that you have all your SEG-D data converted to SEG-Y data, use the following BASH  script to convert a single SEG-Y file to SU:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Provide Input File: ;
read sdata;
segyread tape=${sdata} verbose=1 endian=0 segyclean > ${sdata}.su
echo "New File: ${sdata}.su";
rm -rf binary header;
echo Done.;
```

***Keep in mind that - based on the type of machine you have - endian may need to be set to 1.

Answer (score 1):

for pipe, disk and fixed-block 8mm drives ,you need set param use_stdio=1

segdread tape=1.segd use_stdio=1 > 1.su

Comment: Are you sure? I don't know these programs, but it looks as `stdout` redirection to me.